# Caddy 2 not running in Docker: "cannot assign requested address"

Tags: caddy

I'm trying to run [the official Caddy 2 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/caddy). According to that page, to do that you should run:

```
docker run -p 80:80 \ 
    -v $PWD/index.html:/usr/share/caddy/index.html \
    -v caddy_data:/data \
    caddy
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> {"level":"info","ts":1590185286.853735,"msg":"using provided configuration","config_file":"/etc/caddy/Caddyfile","config_adapter":"caddyfile"}
>   run: loading initial config: loading new config: starting caddy administration endpoint: listen tcp 45.90.28.0:2019: bind: cannot assign requested address

I'm not sure why it's trying to bind to that IP address by default? I tried changing it in the Caddyfile but it still doesn't bind correctly, and anyway that doesn't really solve the underlying issue here.

What could be causing this problem? Should I be using Caddy 1 instead?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Are you running Fedora 32?

Comment: No, running on macOS. Would be great if it's working on Fedora too since I use it as well, but I didn't try it there yet.

Comment: if you type localhost on browser, the caddy welcome page is showing? To run, Caddy is using Caddyfile in /etc/caddy/. I faced a problem like this and I solve it overwriting Caddyfile.

Comment: @DiegoMagalhães Well I got the same error using a Caddyfile but I thought I'd use this command to make it easier for people to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue recently on Linux and the root cause for me was that my ISP supplied routers DNS server was resolving `localhost` to an incorrect IP address.

You might want to try changing your DNS servers to Cloudflare's `1.1.1.1` or Google's `8.8.8.8` servers.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that and it didn't make a difference on mac, but hopefully this helps someone.